# Moving circle using y = mx + b formula in C++

Tags: c++, line, sdl, geometry

So I am writing a program which is moving circle through a line, I need the coordinates of line pixels, so I am using `y = mx + b` formula, but the coordinates of `y` don't change if I use `x++`, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here is a part of my code, where i am using this formula:

```
void draw_picture(Canvas & canvas) {

srand((unsigned)time(0));

PairXY a(200,400);
PairXY b(300,100);
int o=20;
Line l(a,b);
double x=0;
Circle cir(a,o);
draw_circle(cir, canvas);
draw_line(l, canvas);

x=a.x;
for (int i=20; i>0; i--){

  x++;

  ///////

  double m = (b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x);
  double b1 = a.y - m * x;
  double y = m * x + b1; 

  ///////

  a.x=x;
  a.y=y;

  Circle cir1(a,o); 
  draw_circle(cir1, canvas);
 }  
}
```

Comment: What's the type of PairXY's members x and y?

Comment: Ditch the srand() call, it's not useful here (since you aren't using random values) and also calling it more than once per second will mess up your pseudorandom number generation (assuming you are using rand() somewhere).  Also, why are you recalculating m and b1 on every iteration of the loop?  Assuming the line isn't changing, those values shouldn't change either, so you only need to calculate them once.

Comment: The type of PairXY x and y is double.

Forgot to ditch srand() it was part of old program, ok i'll put m and b1 outside the loop

Edit:Big big thx for helping, taking m and b1 out of loop solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double m = (b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x);
double b1 = a.y - m * x;
double y = m * x + b1;
```

C++ does not use what you do with a value to influence how the value is computed. The fact that you are assigning these values to doubles does not cause them to be computed as doubles. Since the math is on integers, you get integer math, which is *definitely* not what you want.

One fix:

```
double m = (b.y-a.y) / (double) (b.x-a.x);
double b1 = a.y - (double) m * x;
double y = m * (double) x + b1;
```

By forcing at least one parameter to be a double in each operation, you force the other to be promoted to a double as well and force the operation to be done on the doubles.

Note that the first line is only safe if `y` is a signed type. If not, `(b.y-a.y)` could underflow. In that case, you need `(b.y - (double) a.y)`.

Comment: I tried adding doubles, but it didn't help.

y still ain't changing :(

Comment: It's because `x` and `y` are still integer types. So if `y` changes by .85, no actual change takes to `a.y` takes place. You created a separate double to hold `x`, which you didn't need (since it always changes by 1), but didn't do that for `y`, which you **do** need (since it changes by less than 1).

Comment: Thx for helping, taking b1 and m out of loop solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you use parametric equation of line:

```
p1(x1, y1, z1) & p2(x2, y2, z2)
```

u shud know p1 & p2.
now for any point p(x, y, z), use the parameter 't'.

```
t = p2 - p1;//this gives you 't'
p = p1 + t *(p2 -p1)//you know p1, p2, t...so get values of p.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the types of the pair's `x` and `y`, my guess is that the line

```
double m = (b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x);
```

is causing the problem. If the two values are `int`, and the first is lower, it will always return `0`. For m to be the actual value, you need an explicit cast to bool:

```
double m = (double)(b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x);
```